# Another tool for sourcesafe replacement

Tags: version-control, sourcesafe-6.0

We've been using Microsoft Sourcesafe for a long time. It never failed us, but sometimes we had problems with it...like:

- Files disapearing
- Sometimes, when someone did some changes in a file, and checked it in, after a check out, the file wouldn't have the changes.
- etc, etc

We're looking for another version control tool for our projects. Preferably, an easy-to-use one.

What do you guys sugest?

Comment: That sounds to me like it did fail you after all!

Comment: The time has come for us to change it. These problems seldom occured. But you when they did, we got screwed. Big time. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather stick with Microsoft, then there's [Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/ff637362.aspx).

Alternatively some other popular solutions that I've used and can vouch for:

- [Git](http://git-scm.com/) (although, this has a bit of a learning curve to use properly, but VERY powerful and my preferred source control system)
- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/)
- [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/)

This is quite a subjective question though - so I'd recommend doing a bit of research yourself to see what most matches your requirements. Whatever you use, you'll notice a huge step up from Sourcesafe however!

Comment: I'll check those out. Thanks @Dan!